# Can I update Test Jira using Prod Jira

Tags: linux, ssh, jira

our test system has not been updated in some time, and its becoming a bit redundant, since the tickets are outdated. We use mostly Microsoft serves, but our Jira is on Linux so I need some help with the commands. I managed to log in via SSH, but I am stuck. Could not find a guide online including commands. Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Jira stores it's data in the JIRA_HOME directory and the database

If both systems are on the same version, all you need to do is to export the data from your production DB into your test system DB, and copy the contents of the JIRA_HOME to the JIRA_HOME on your test system.

If you're using the same type of DB on prod and dev, this should be trivial.
If you're not using the same type of DB, you should really should.

Comment: That is quite helpful, but could you advise me which commands I can use to do that?

Comment: Can you tell me what kind of DB you have in use?

You'll also need the location of the JIRA_HOME on your test and production system.
What kind of linux are you using? Do you have a GUI, or only command line?

I'm also suggesting that you're using a test system you can administrate. If you're not experienced with linux, it might be a good idea to use another windows box for the test system as well.

Comment: So we use Postgresql I do have the location of jira home /var/atlassian/application-data/jira the linux is Amazon Linux AMI, only command line, no GUI. I am trying to restore the test system from PROD.